Why is my shower leaking from the diverter?
I just moved into a place and the shower is leaking from the diverter (not the faucet) when set to bath, but not shower.
My initial thought was to replace the cartridge, but is it likely that this is something else?

After removing the trim, This is what I have:

After removing the sleeve, this is what I have

I put an o ring after the bolt (there wasn't one there) and put everything back, but there is still a leak present
After removing the hex brass fitting, this is what I have:

I replaced these two O Rings (Didn't have one for the small, thick one):

But the leak is still present:

Could it be the other one that needs replacing? Or is there something else I'm missing?

I added the pertinent pic from your comment.

You need to take the trim off and view the workings underneath. This will tell you if the diverter is serviceable. It may also help identify the brand.
Once that is known, so simply replace the needed seals.
UPDATE
Since the new pic was added to your post:
Remove the diverter sleeve, ( There is a flat indicated with the blue line) That is to provide a hold for a tool to turn the sleeve off.  Under that should be the seal. Probably an "O" ring.
While you have things apart the cartridge seals should be replaced. (Yellow lines)

New seals should take care of your problem.
The water still running may be a leaking shutoff, or residual water in the lines that will eventually stop.

Right - probably just calcium buildup.

This is what I'm faced with. Should I remove the diverter? https://i.sstatic.net/DdjVhoO4.jpg and  https://i.sstatic.net/4mo6aiLj.jpg Also, the water seems to be perpetually running, even though this is off at the mains. Could this be contributing to the issue?

@HoneyDo actually, I'd say less calcium buildup and more simply the rubber seals in the cartridge aging and wearing away.  The rubber deteriorates, losing thickness, and thus doesn't seal as well.  If you ever open up an old plumbing item with rubber seals and handled them, you'll see that the rubber kind of just rubs off on your fingers.

What tool can I use to take the sleeve off? Just got back from the hardware store with a mixer tap spanner set they recommended, but it didn't work. It was too small

I would try "slip lock" pliers.  https://www.acehardware.com/solid-joint-pliers/2262038?store=18608&gad_source=1&gclid=Cj0KCQjwu-63BhC9ARIsAMMTLXTZOFY3FYljIa58jCaDk4lw_hylzkxdi4A3zywYuYMtF5eSmuRs7FIaAq1hEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds

I have updated my question

This is a good answer.   It is almost always the rubber seals.    Finding exact matches...   lot of luck and sometimes you call a plumber that has 40 sizes in their van.

@TravisJohnson, unscrew the hex head brass fitting. I'm sure the seal is behind that.

Thank you for your continuous help. I have updated my question.

Any other ideas? The hardware shop isn't much help.

Replace all the rummer parts on that stem.  Where to find them?  Probably the best bet is a plumbing supply store.

The hardware store didn't have any, neither did the plumbing supply store. The hardware store even asked the original manufacturer for a spare part, but they couldn't help either as it's long discontinued.
In the end, I found somebody who was selling the same brand and model of shower mixer pretty cheap onine, so I just took the diverter out of that and replaced it. All is up and running again now.
Thanks for all your help.

Yeah, old fixtures can be a pain to get part for.  Glad that you got it handled.
